# Big O symbol (order of) and siunitx

Tags: siunitx, mathcal

I want to write that a quantity is of the order of say, 10 m/s. I have currently used the syntax below, but is there a way to write it completely into siunitx, or is the one considered below a reasonable way to do it?

```
$\mathcal{O}(\SI{10}{\meter\per\second})$
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about a [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)-based solution? You get to decide whether to change `\mathcal{O}` to just the plain `O` without search/replace within your whole document. :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setlength\parskip{\smallskipamount}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\BigOSI[2]%
  {\mathcal{O}}{(}{)}{}%
  {\SI{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

$\BigOSI{10}{\meter\per\second}$\par
$\BigOSI[\big]{10}{\meter\per\second}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Big O]

Comment: Using it, I am not getting the bar symbol

    $Z=\BigOSI{}{\bar{r}(\bar{r}+\bar{\lambda})}$

Comment: @user1942348, in your case you should not use suggested command adopted to specific use but just $Z=\mathcal{O} \bar{r}(\bar{r}+\bar{\lambda})$